# How do I rotate components when designing a ship?

Tags: stardrive

In the Stardrive beta, is it possible to rotate components during ship design in the shipyard?

Comment: You can rotate the firing arc of a component by clicking on the component, then clicking and dragging the arc to where you want it.

Comment: @StarPilot post that as an answer, and you will get my upvote

Comment: I didn't post it as an answer originally because it didn't seem complete to me. I know how to rotate the firing arcs, but haven't found a way to rotate the actual pieces at the time of this comment's post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rotate the firing arc of a component by clicking on the component, then clicking and dragging the arc to where you want it